# How to drop subdataframe if it contains more than 40% NaN Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Hello everyone i have such problem:

I have panel data for 400.000 objects and i want to drop objects if it contains more that 40% NaNs

For example:

```
               inn  time_reg   revenue1    balans1    equity1  opprofit1  \
0        0101000021      2006   457000.0   115000.0    28000.0    29000.0   
1        0101000021      2007  1943000.0   186000.0   104000.0    99000.0   
2        0101000021      2008  2812000.0   318000.0   223000.0   127000.0   
3        0101000021      2009  2673000.0   370000.0   242000.0    39000.0   
4        0101000021      2010  3240000.0   435000.0    45000.0        NaN   
...             ...       ...        ...        ...        ...        ...   
4081810  9909403758      2003  6943000.0  2185000.0  2136000.0   -97000.0   
4081811  9909403758      2004  6504000.0  2245000.0  2196000.0   -34000.0   
4081812  9909403758      2005        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
4081813  9909403758      2006        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
4081814  9909403758      2007        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

        grossprofit1  netprofit1  currentassets1  stliabilities1  
0             92000.0     18000.0        105000.0         87000.0  
1            189000.0     76000.0        176000.0         82000.0  
2            472000.0    119000.0        308000.0         95000.0  
3            483000.0     29000.0        360000.0        128000.0  
4                 NaN     35000.0             NaN             NaN  
...               ...         ...             ...             ...  
4081810     2365000.0    -59000.0        253000.0         49000.0  
4081811     2278000.0     60000.0        425000.0         49000.0  
4081812           NaN         NaN             NaN             NaN  
4081813           NaN         NaN             NaN             NaN  
4081814           NaN         NaN             NaN             NaN
```

I have such dataframe, and for each subdataframe grouped by (inn,time_reg) i need to drop it if total nans in columns (revenue1 balans1 equity1 opprofit1   grossprofit1    netprofit1  currentassets1  stliabilities1) more than 40%.

I have an idea to do it in a loop but this it takes a lot of time
For example:

```
                inn  time_reg   revenue1    balans1    equity1  opprofit1  \
4081809  9909403758      2002  6078000.0  2270000.0  2195000.0   -32000.0   
4081810  9909403758      2003  6943000.0  2185000.0  2136000.0   -97000.0   
4081811  9909403758      2004  6504000.0  2245000.0  2196000.0   -34000.0   
4081812  9909403758      2005        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
4081813  9909403758      2006        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
4081814  9909403758      2007        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

         grossprofit1  netprofit1  currentassets1  stliabilities1  
4081809     1324000.0         NaN        234000.0         75000.0  
4081810     2365000.0    -59000.0        253000.0         49000.0  
4081811     2278000.0     60000.0        425000.0         49000.0  
4081812           NaN         NaN             NaN             NaN  
4081813           NaN         NaN             NaN             NaN  
4081814           NaN         NaN             NaN             NaN
```

This subdataframe should be droped, coz it contains more than 40% nans

```
      inn  time_reg    revenue1    balans1   equity1  opprofit1  \
0   0101000021      2006    457000.0   115000.0   28000.0    29000.0   
1   0101000021      2007   1943000.0   186000.0  104000.0    99000.0   
2   0101000021      2008   2812000.0   318000.0  223000.0   127000.0   
3   0101000021      2009   2673000.0   370000.0  242000.0    39000.0   
4   0101000021      2010   3240000.0   435000.0   45000.0        NaN   
5   0101000021      2011   3480000.0   610000.0   71000.0        NaN   
6   0101000021      2012   4820000.0   710000.0  139000.0   149000.0   
7   0101000021      2013   5200000.0   790000.0  148000.0   170000.0   
8   0101000021      2014   5450000.0   830000.0  155000.0   180000.0   
9   0101000021      2015   5620000.0   860000.0  164000.0   189000.0   
10  0101000021      2016   5860000.0   885000.0  175000.0   200000.0   
11  0101000021      2017  15112000.0  1275000.0  298000.0   323000.0   

    grossprofit1  netprofit1  currentassets1  stliabilities1  
0        92000.0     18000.0        105000.0         87000.0  
1       189000.0     76000.0        176000.0         82000.0  
2       472000.0    119000.0        308000.0         95000.0  
3       483000.0     29000.0        360000.0        128000.0  
4            NaN     35000.0             NaN             NaN  
5            NaN     61000.0             NaN             NaN  
6       869000.0    129000.0        700000.0        571000.0  
7      1040000.0    138000.0        780000.0        642000.0  
8      1090000.0    145000.0        820000.0        675000.0  
9      1124000.0    154000.0        850000.0        696000.0  
10     1172000.0    165000.0        875000.0        710000.0  
11     3023000.0    288000.0       1265000.0        977000.0
```

This subdataframe contains less than 40% nans and must be in final dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Would a loop be too slow too if you used a numpy/pandas function for the counting? You could use `someDataFrame.isnull().sum().sum()`.

Probably a lot faster than writing your own loop to go over all the values in a dataframe, since those libraries tend to have very efficient implementations of those kinds of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method of `pd.DataFrame.groupby`.
This allows you to pass a function that indicates whether a subframe should be filtered or not (in this case if it contains over 40% NaNs in the relevant columns). To get that information, you can use `numpy` to count the nans as in `getNanFraction`:

```py
def getNanFraction(df):
    nanCount = np.sum(np.isnan(df.drop("inn", axis=1).values))
    return nanCount/len(df)


df.groupby("inn").filter(lambda x: getNanFraction(x) < 0.4 )
```